# Random text for button in android

Tags: java, android

Example I have 3 buttons

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and I have text to random as bellow

```
private static final String[] answers = {"a", "b", "c", "Vowel", "d", "e", "f"};
String q = answers[rgenerator.nextInt(answers.length)];
button1.setText(q);
button2.setText(q);
button3.setText(q);
```

Example I start activity 5 times to random:

```
1st activity start random look like: a, c, Vowel
2st activity start random look like: b, Vowel, a
3st activity start random look like: Vowel, e, b
4st activity start random look like: a, e, Vowel
5st activity start random look like: Vowel, b, f
```

All the time activity start must have "Vowel" setText to the 1 of 3 buttons all the times when activity refresh/start.

I am really stuck on it..

Comment: you want to set text as Vowel in all the buttons.??

Comment: No, I mean Vowel have to appear all the time when random for button. example: 1st start (a, b, Vowel), 2st start (Vowel, f, e), 3st start (c, Vowel, e).....n ... must have Vowel inside random.

Comment: plz rephrase your question. Its not clear

Comment: hi Andro Selva, already refreshed my question. Thank q sir.

Comment: have you tried that.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your can try this for both case:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 boolean vowel_added = false;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (numbers.size()<=3) {
      int randomInteger = rnd.nextInt(answers.length());
      if (!numbers.contains(randomInteger)) {

            if (answers[randomInteger]).equalsIgnoreCase("Vowel"))
             {
                 if (! vowel_added)
                 {
                   vowel_added = true;
                   numbers.add(randomInteger);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 numbers.add(randomInteger);
             }
       }
    }
    if (! vowel_added) {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(numbers.size());//this random to set the index of vowel at random position
      numbers.set(index,3);//you can find the index of one vowel and put here
    }
    button1.setText(answers[numbers.get(0)]);
    button2.setText(answers[numbers.get(1)]);
    button3.setText(answers[numbers.get(2)]);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Dear Michael Sth, thanks you for your help but it couldn't help me to solve. can you please give me more clue on your code because I think I made mistake when I insert your code to my project. Thanks q sir.

Comment: @user1731690 You can place it in the onCreate Method or in a seperate method

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks you so much it's was solved my project. thanks you again Michael. so, if I have 5 button, i have to change numbers.size()<=3 to numbers.size() <= 5 , right?

Comment: Hi Michael, Again, I was stuck on if my array has two value something like this: {"a", "b", "c", "Vowel", "d", "e", "f", "Vowel", "g"}; .. so in the array list has 2 "Vowel", so I want to show only 1, based on your code above some times it show 2 "Vowel" on the button, what should I do in your code, sir?

Comment: Dear Michael, I really really don't know how to say thank you. You help me again. your code is work very very well and it's what I need and my project can be go to the big one as my dream by your help. Million thank Michael.

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstRandomNum  = (int)(Math.random()*6);  // Generate Random Number
int secondRandomNum = (int)(Math.random()*6);  // Generate Random Number

int indexOfVowel = 3; // As you said one text must be Vowel , its index is 3

Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q1);
Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q2);
Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q3);
if(firstRandomNum != indexOfVowel && secondRandomNum != indexOfVowel ) {

 b1.setText(""+answers[firstRandomNum]);
 b2.setText(""+answers[secondRandomNum ]);
 b3.setText(""+answers[indexOfVowel]);
} else {
    b1.setText(""+answers[firstRandomNum]);
    b2.setText(""+answers[secondRandomNum ]);
    b3.setText(""+answers[indexOfVowel+1]);
}
```

above code is just to help you, it is not complete logic or error free

Comment: Dear Yahya Arshad, I got what is your code do, let me try again by insert your method to my code. thank Yahya.

Comment: Hi Yahya Arshad, I tested its working well but Vowel alway appear on Button 3 and some times appear Vowel double. So, what should I do sir.

Comment: One possible solution could be, that at which button object you was displayed 'Vowel' and save that to shared preferences, i.e if last Vowel, displayed was on q1, save '1' in shared preferences, and when you restart your activity, retrive value from shared preferences if it is 1 than next object should be q2(2) and save 2 in shared preferences,